# Saving webpage as txt (not the webpage code)

Tags: java, web, save

I want to save a webpage as txtfile.
I don't want to save the code, I don't want the code at all, I want to save the page itself as txtfile and then I know what I want to do with the txt file.

I use the below code to open the page

```
import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.net.URI;


public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    Desktop d = Desktop.getDesktop();
    String url = "http://www.google.com";
    d.browse(new URI(url));
}
```

}

As well I want to make the browse hidden, can it be done?

to make it more clear, to save a page as txt, you press CTRL + S and then choose txt.
I don't want the code of the page at all, I tried with buffered reader and input stream but this is not what I need at all because they give me the code of the URL which I don't need.
Thank you for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

your best bet is using http://jsoup.org/

this will get the whole page (I mean, with code):

```
public static String getHTML(String urlToRead) throws Exception {

        if (!urlToRead.startsWith("http"))
            urlToRead = "http://" + urlToRead;

        final StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        final URL url = new URL(urlToRead);
        final HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
//      @SuppressWarnings("unused")
//      final int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
        final BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));

        String line;
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null)
            result.append(line);
        rd.close();

        return result.toString();
    }
```

then you can create the Document:

```
final Document doc = Jsoup.parse(content);
```

and from there on, you are on your own getting a list of `div`s, `span`s, and `p`s...

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I'm still totally new to Java, and the Jsoup is not working for me in Eclipse, it can't be imported and I don't know how to create, as well I don't know what is the list of div S,Span and P.....

Comment: @AboelmagdSaad You should probably learn some basic HTML before you start working with web pages. Learn to walk before you run.

Comment: @Exceptyon
You are right for sure, thank you for the hint